# Google Charts Timeline Labels not being displayed inside the box

Tags: charts, google-visualization, timeline

Labels overflow outside the box. Some lables are well inside the box. Others just draw outside.

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
     var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Term' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

    dataTable.addRows([
      [ '1', 'George Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ '2', 'John Adams', new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ '2', 'Johndc Adams', new Date(1790, 2, 4),  new Date(1810, 2, 4) ],
      [ '4', 'Johndc Adams', new Date(1770, 2, 4),  new Date(1810, 2, 4) ],
      [ '3', 'Thomas Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
```

[image]

Comment: this is the default functionality if the labels will not fit inside the bar

Comment: Thanks for the response but that was not the problem. I set the width to 1000px and it worked. earlier it was 2000px. It's a buggyAPI. One more bug. the date range is 2018, 06, 02 to 2018, 06, 30 and it's showing 2nd july to 30th july. When it should show 2nd june to 30th june

Comment: okay came to know that javascript considers january 0 and not 1. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date